# sort a liste by distance (latitude,longitude)

Tags: c#, mysql

i have this code working 100% that calculate distance between two objects

```
 public double CalculateDistance(string storelocator_id, BO_MAGASIN magasin)
{
  double response = 0;
  var getMagasin = _context.Magasin.FirstOrDefault(x => x.storelocator_id.Equals(storelocator_id));
  double distance = 0;
  var myMagasin = _context.Magasin.FirstOrDefault(x => x.storelocator_id.Equals("1"));
  string sql;

  var magasins = _context.Magasin.ToList();
  if (storelocator_id != null)
  {
    string latitude = getMagasin.latitude;
    string longitude = getMagasin.longitude;
    string magasin_latitude = magasin.latitude;
    string magasin_longitude = magasin.longitude;
    sql = "set @pt1= point(" + latitude + "," + longitude + ");  set @pt2= point(" + magasin_latitude + "," + magasin_longitude + "); SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(@pt1, @pt2)/1000";
    try
    {
      MySqlDataReader reader = null;
      string selectCmd = sql;
      string dbConn = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("Default").Value;
      var conn = new MySqlConnection(dbConn);
      conn.Open();

      MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectCmd, conn);
      reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      if (reader.Read())
      {
        response = double.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
        if (distance > response)
        {
          distance = response;
        }
      }
      conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }   
}
  return distance;
}
```

i have other code that returns liste of BO_MAGASIN but now i want to sort this list by distance any one have an idea how can i do this ?

Comment: If you are obtaining a list of `BO_MAGASIN` from the database then the most performant way to obtain a list of objects sorted by distance is by writing a SQL query that `SELECT`s the objects then `ORDER BY` the distance. Your question hints that you have a C# list already pulled from the database then you want to feed each item through your `CalculateDistance()` function (calling to the database multiple times) and use a client-side Linq query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the distance between those points in C# using the following function (uses [spherical triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry) to calculate the distance)

```
    public double GetDistanceInMeters(BO_MAGASIN entry, BO_MAGASIN other)
    {
        const double earthRadius = 6371.009; // [km]
        const double radian = Math.PI / 180;

        var thisLatitude = entry.latitude;
        var otherLatitude = other.latitude;
        var thisLongitude = entry.longitude;
        var otherLongitude = other.longitude;

        var deltaLongitude = Math.Abs(thisLongitude - otherLongitude);

        thisLatitude *= radian;
        otherLatitude *= radian;
        deltaLongitude *= radian;

        var factor = Math.Pow(10, -3); //result in meters

        var cos = Math.Cos(deltaLongitude) * Math.Cos(thisLatitude) * Math.Cos(otherLatitude) +
                  Math.Sin(thisLatitude) * Math.Sin(otherLatitude);

        return earthRadius * Math.Acos(cos) / factor;
    }
```

To sort the list by distance use Linq `.OrderBy()`.

BTW: If you want the result to be in km just remove the `factor` or set i to `1` (one).